# Does update allow integers as keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I can update a dictionary using other means.
I'm curios about this specific way of updating a dictionary.

Update works (see below)

```
dict1 = {1: 'cat', 2: 'dog'}
dict1.update(k3 = 'blabla', k4 = 'blabla')
print(dict1)
```

Update does not work (see below)

```
dict1 = {1: 'cat', 2: 'dog'}
dict1.update(3 = 'blabla', 4 = 'blabla')
print(dict1)
```

Can I update a dictionary using key value pairs in this way when the key is an integer?

Comment: No, keyword arguments *must always be valid python identifiers*, and for `dict.update`, will only ever allow string keys if you use the keyword argument form

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga direct and to the point. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, and actually not quite correct, if you read the answer below, it accepts any string, not just valid Python identifiers, *if* you use double-splatting, but I suspect you only care about the `func(key_arg=value)` form

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the clarification. My focus is integers, but this topic did make me aware of myString.isidentifier() function. Also, unpacking is not necessary when using update() as in dict1.update(dict2).

Comment: right but that uses a positional argument, I was talking about named arguments, which I thought was what we were talking about

Comment: `dict1.update(**{1: 2})` *does not* give you the same thing as `dict1.update({1: 2})`,  because `dict1.update(**{1: 2})` raises an error

Comment: Agreed, now I think you'll also agree that dict1.update(**{1: 2}) is not the same as dict1.update( 1 = 2 ) , so how does update deal with an unpacked dictionary. It's not the same as using named arguments as in dict1.update( 1 = 2 ). I'm curious to know what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Because `update(1=2)` is a *syntax error*, it doesn't even *compile*. `update(**{1:2})` is a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *exactly* like this. Keyword arguments must be strings. Interestingly enough, you are able to include keyword arguments that aren't legal identifiers; for example, you can do `dict1.update(**{"-": 1})`, but you cannot do `dict1.update(**{1: 2})`.

You can do `dict1.update({1: 2, 3: 4})` though. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVqHa0ErBSEfB2ErBpJYrUa@0ICWxJFUDJGqgo2BkpWBYq8nFVVCUmVeikaj5/z8A)

Comment: There's no need to unpack dictionaries when using update().

Comment: @user3112576 I know that. I was just demonstrating my point that strings, even non-identifiers, work but numbers do not.

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete the comments once I'm clear.
My original question had keyword arguments dict1.update(3 = 'blabla').
So are you saying that dict1.update(**{1: 2}) is the same as dict1.update(1 = 2).
If that's the case is dict1.update(**{"-": 1}) the same as dict1.update( - = 1)?

Comment: @user3112576 Well, sort of. `dict1.update(- = 1)` of course will result in an error but it is that idea.

Comment: 'sort of' 'that idea' , not to be an a** but you've piqued my curiosity and I need a concrete answer. Why is it that dict1.update(**{"-": 1}) works but dict1.update(- = 1) does not?

Comment: @user3112576 No worries about it. `dict1.update(- = 1)`. Simply put, the syntax for `a.update(b = c)` simply doesn't work unless `b` is an identifier - after all, you're telling the function (`a.update`) that its parameter with variable name `b` should be set to `c`, and since `-` can't be a variable name, it can't be a keyword argument. Also, it would be really inconsistent to try to parse `dict1.update(- = 1)` and you'd get all sorts of weird behavior. I suspect the reason `dict1.update(**{"-": 1})` works is literally just because a) they forgot or b) didn't think it was important to check.